# Wi-Fi Calling feature on Pixel - How do I tell if it is using it?

Tags: wi-fi, calls, google-pixel

I came across the Wi-Fi **calling** option in settings and thought I'd give it a try since my cellular **phone** connection with Verizon is very spotty at my house.

It is supposed to use whichever has the strongest signal between wi-fi or cellular.  Under the settings it says "Cellular Preferred" which I don't see how to change, although it has a setting for "Roaming preference" which I changed to Wi-Fi, but this doesn't change the "Cellular Preferred" label on the main settings screen.

I'm trying to determine if it is actually using the wi-fi connection when making a call.  There is no indication on the status bar that is any different whether it is turned on or not.  Theoretically it should be using the wi-fi since it is a much stronger signal.

To be clear, I'm talking about using the actual "phone", I'm not talking about wi-fi vs cellular data transfers, which is more obvious as to which you are using.

Is anyone aware of how to tell which one it is using?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of where you found this option in the settings? Is it just Pixel or Pixel XL?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung, so behaviour might not be identical (although a quick google seems to suggest it is near enough). When my phone determines that cellular signal is not strong enough and switches to wifi-calling, an icon does appear in the status bar next to the wifi indicator. It looks like a phone icon with the wifi logo above it. The phone icon in the dialler also changes to this modified version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply etmus.  I do get the phone icon, but I get it regardless of whether wifi calling is on or off.  Not a huge deal, time should tell whether I am getting wifi or not, assuming it works as intended I should start to see my phone call quality be consistently better.  Right not its spotty, some times it ok, other times the other side says I'm breaking up, which isn't surprising since my dBm hovers around -115dBm