# How to turn on Wi-Fi Calling in Google Pixel 1 (not XL)?

Tags: wi-fi, settings, calls, google-pixel

As a preliminary question to [Wi-Fi Calling feature on Pixel - How do I tell if it is using it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181828/wi-fi-calling-feature-on-pixel-how-do-i-tell-if-it-is-using-it), how and where does one enable it in the first place?

Should it appear in the phone app's settings **or** in the general settings? Can you post a screenshot?

And does it only appear in either of them if the phone company supports it for this phone?

Comment: Yes, for the last Para

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the Mobile Network needs to support Wi-Fi calling.

From **Settings** -> **Network & Internet** -> **Mobile Network** -> [tap on]**Advanced** and scroll down a bit you should see something similar to the following which was taken on a Pixel 2 with Android 10.

[image: Screenshot of Pixel 2 with Android 10 Carrier Settings]

Comment: I've accepted but are you sure Pixel 2 is identical to 1 in this case? I don't see this option at all so I must assume it's due to the mobile network.

Comment: You should then tell us what carrier you are using (and perhaps what region), otherwise this is what I see with Google/Android software.

Comment: Israel/Partner.